# Spritefonts gets very messed up when scaling up

Tags: xna, c#, fonts

I'm recoding a retro video game, but because the original resolution is very low, I scale everything up. I render to a renderTarget and render the renderTarget to the target resolution.

I'm using my spriteBatch like this:

`_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null);`

This allows upscaling with keeping the pixels as they are.
It works fine, but the spritefont gets really messed up:[image: Messed up spriteFont]

Any idea how to fix that? When I create the spriteFont with an extremly large size and give it a low scale to the drawString method, it looks about the same.

Comment: You could draw text and numbers to other RT and scale it with Linear sampler, then draw it on top of the first RT, maybe it can work? Also, Did you tried turning on mipmaps?

Comment: Where can I set mipmapping on fonts? I can only see that option for textures. Your renderTarget solution will work I believe, but what happens when a texture has to be drawn above text? Does not happen so far but could. But I think a 3rd renderTarget which draws textures after text could solve that too.

Comment: I just guessed, I'm not sure if you can enable mipmaps in spritefonts :P